# What are the limits of Magneto's magnetic field?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Is there any source about the strongest magnetic field Magneto can generate?

Currently the strongest magnetic fields in continuous use (a few Tesla, maybe up to around 10 Tesla) are strong enough to make a human feel dizzy if he runs through the magnetic field, as the nerves generate enough current due to the electromotive force. This means that a moving magnetic field a few orders of magnitudes stronger could incapacitate or even kill a human.

If Magneto can generate a magnetic field stronger than an MRI machine, he could incapacitate or kill people just by generating an alternating magnetic field, even if no metals are around. Was this ability ever addressed, or just is his "power" not strong enough for this?

Comment: Change in magnetic field leads to electric field. Then this electric field can create electric arc between the surrounding metals and can pass right through his helm. Frying his brain. He flys with the metal inventory on him.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**For all intents and purposes, [Magneto of Earth-616](http://marvel.wikia.com/Max_Eisenhardt_%28Earth-616%29) has no effective upper limits to his magnetic powers. He is considered an Omega Class mutant, a mutant so powerful, his abilities can affect or even destroy the entire world. His powers are so great he has lifted a 30,000 ton submarine from the depths of the ocean, resisted the force of a nuclear detonation, manipulated electromagnetic fields to generate wormholes to travel through space, and even stripped the adamantium from Wolverine's skeleton, forcefully and painfully. His power defies almost all of the known physics of the Marvel Universe.**

[image: Drawing the adamantium from Wolverine]

*Drawing the adamantium from Wolverine's skeleton, yes the material that is supposedly unable to be affected by any normal force in the Marvel Universe once it has set...*

- Magnetokinesis: Magneto has a near-limitless control of all forms of magnetism, whether natural or artificial, to manipulate any metal. He can manipulate magnetic fields at the planetary level.
- Generating Magnetic Force Fields: He is able to generate a forcefield capable of repelling forces equivalent to a nuclear attack. He has successfully defended himself against Thor and his hammer Mjolnir, Iron Man's impressive array of weapons and the wielders of the Phoenix force. He has single-handedly fought against entire teams of heroes and villains.
- Magnetic Flight: By connecting himself to the magnetic field of the Earth, Magneto is capable of flight at supersonic speeds. He can also repel himself against the metals in the surface of a planet if the planet has no intrinsic magnetic field.
- Molecular matter manipulation: His magnetic field manipulations are so powerful he can reorder the molecular structure of matter by manipulating the electromagnetic force bonds.
- His control of his magnetic powers is so precise, he can manipulate the iron in a human's blood, causing aneurysms, strokes or heart attacks. He is even able to create a magnetic field strong enough to suppress the power of thought by suppressing the brain's electromagnetic field. It is likely the same magnetic field which makes him more resistant to psionic abilities.

This is not an all inclusive list of Magneto's powers, it is designed to simply give you a matter of comparison against a device such as an MRI machine; there is NO CONTEST.

Comment: He can be a healer, too. He used his powers to diagnose young and sickly Maggot's problems and remove Maggott's symbiotic metal slugs from his gut for the first time. (Maggott rejected him immediately after - shame. He'd have been a great member of the brotherhood.)

Comment: Well... Then how on earth is he not ruling the world ?

Answer (score 0):

Saving Shadowcat from the giant bullet she phased through the Earth at any extremely long range.  Plus it was rapidly moving away from the Earth at the time and at been for awhile.

Comment: When was that? Which issue, year?

Comment: @Jenayah I think this refers to [*Uncanny X-Men* Vol. 1 #520](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_520) (and following) when Magneto retrieves the space bullet that Kitty Pryde is trapped in.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  As noted, you should add more details to your question - what comic did this appear in and when, and also explain the size, distance and timeframe involved in what Magento; otherwise this doesn't really help define his limits.  If it was only a car-sized object at a few hundred km distance it's not really that big a deal.

Answer (score -2):

Magneto is a man of honor, he doesn't kill heroes, even when they repeatedly harass him. I felt little sympathy when wolverine got his adamant ripped out of him..he forced the fight on magneto.  As for why magneto isn't ruling the world..marvel writers often water magneto down in fights because he is so powerful. Even on comic vine fans often water down his abilities in fights so their heroes have a chance of winning.  Magneto vs hulk for example..first thing hulk fans do is remove mags ability to affect the iron in hulks blood.

Comment: This only addresses the last, tangential, point in the question and not the main question about the limits of his magnetic field. Would you like me to convert it to a comment instead of an answer?